# Windows 10 disappered from boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have been running with dual boot between 20.04 and Windows 10 for some time, but now I can no longer boot into Windows. The option has mysteriously disappeared from the boot menu. The only thing that I have been doing is to install Ubuntu updates whenever requested to do so.

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-58-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-52-generic
find: ‘/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/el-GR’: Input/output error
find: ‘/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/es-ES’: Input/output error
find: ‘/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/fi-FI’: Input/output error
find: ‘/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/sl-SI’: Input/output error
find: ‘/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/sv-SE’: Input/output error
find: ‘/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/uk-UA’: Input/output error
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

When I try to run boot repair I get this message:
"LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB)."

Since I have already been running dual boot then I seriously doubt that I need to change anything in the BIOS.

I don't want to re-install Windows so before I risk messing things up I want to ask you guys out there how to proceed.

Kind regards,
Christian

sudo parted -l
Model: ATA SanDisk SSD PLUS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags

1      1049kB  556MB   555MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag

2      556MB   661MB   105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp

3      661MB   677MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres

4      677MB   550GB   549GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata

5      550GB   1000GB  450GB   ext4

Model: ATA WDC WD20EARX-00P (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ext3         boot

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Model: ASUS BW-16D1HT (scsi)
Disk /dev/sr0: 41.8GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
1      0.00B  41.8GB  41.8GB  udf

test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios

efi

Comment: Run the following commands: `sudo parted -l` and
`test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios`. Post output into question.

Comment: @PaulBenson I have added the information you requested

Comment: Well the good news is you have a Win10 partition of nearly 550 GB (sda4), if you can confirm that. Can you also confirm that the 450 GB on the same disk is your Ubuntu partition? The next thing I need to see is the output of `grep -i -A10 Windows /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.  What is the 2TB WD disk used for? On which partition do you store your data?

Comment: @PaulBenson The answer is Yes, Yes, and there is no longer a Windows entry in the grub.cfg file. I guess that I got the config overwritten when I ran update-grub. At first I thought it was just some easy fix from reading some posts on the internet but when Windows was not re-appearing as a boot option after running update-grub then I decided to ask for advice instead of risking making irreversible damage.
The 2TB disk is just an old drive used for data storage but my documents and such all lie on the SSD drive (that holds both Ubuntu and Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Find the UUID of your EFI partition in Terminal as follows:-

`lsblk -o name,partlabel,fstype,uuid|grep -i efi`. It's shown in the last column, and you will need this shortly.

Make a copy of your *grub.cfg* file from Terminal - `sudo cp /boot/grub/grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub2.cfg`.

Open *grub.cfg* with `sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Click the 3 vertical dots (top right panel) and select *Find*, and in the box enter *menuentry 'Ubuntu'*. That first Ubuntu menu entry will highlight. Then scroll several lines down to the closing brace after the *initrd*...line. Make a new paragraph after this closing brace, then add/paste the following lines:

```
 menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda4)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-UUID' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  UUID
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root UUID
        fi
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
    }
```

1. Note, where I've put *UUID* (uppercase) in the code you now need to substitute the actual UUID you found earlier. There are 3 instances of it. With the first one (first line) there is no space after the hyphen. Make sure the last line of code is a closing brace as shown, then save the file. Do not update grub, but reboot.
2. Note this grub entry assumes your Win 10 booting files have not been altered or corrupted, as any missing or defiled entries in the ESP will result in booting errors for Windows. Grub isn't responsible once it hands over control to Windows.

Comment: The Windows boot manager must be faulty because it didn't work. Now I don't even get to see the grub boot menu. Seems that it tries to do something during boot but gives up and boots the default which is Ubuntu
If I run the Windows Startup Repair will it then wipe grub? Or has Windows come so far as to accept dual boot systems?
I remember having restored Windows boot manager way back with 16.04 but that wiped grub and I had to reinstall grub. Fortunately I was able to access to my Ubuntu installation back then.
But isn't there a more up-to-date way of repairing dual boot?

Comment: What I suggested should not affect your grub menu, other than add that entry if you copied correctly. Have you tried booting from UEFI menu? This bypasses grub and you need to quickly tap one of the Fn buttons as soon as machine starts to boot. Which Fn button depends on your make/model of computer. (F12 on mine). I suggest failing that, you boot to Live Ubuntu and perform a [boot-repair](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/) which should also restore your grub. It won't fix Windows though.

Comment: Also you can restore from your grub copy to your original grub from Ubuntu - `sudo cp /boot/grub/grub2.cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Then reboot. Win10 works fine as dual boot with Ubuntu. Win10 PE Repair won't wipe grub, but will probably replace it as boot manager, so you will keep booting to Win10 instead.

Comment: Trying to boot from the UEFI menu also fails and it returns to the menu when I try to boot Windows. If you say that the way forward is to use the Windows Startup Repair tool and then be prepared to reinstall Grub then I'll give it a try

Comment: Do you want to try and resolve this on *Chat* as this is getting a bit long-winded now for comments and there is a bit more 'digging' that needs to be done?

Comment: Hi @Paul Benson,
Sorry for the absence but I ran out of time and had a lot of work to do. So I had to park this but now I am ready to pick where we left, if it is ok with you?

Comment: @Christian Wittrock We can, but it's better to do this on 'chat' as this thread is getting too long, if you want to do it that way.

Comment: yes that would probably be a good idea. I don't have privileges to start a chat myself so I'll have to ask to you to initiate one.
Eventually we can delete all non-informative comments and just add the step-by-step solution

Comment: If you click on 'Chat' below and look for a room I've opened called 'Discussion PaulB - Christian Witrock', click on that and we should be able to resume. You may have to login or register with 'Chat'  first. Can't remember the procedure exactly.

Comment: I can't see the room and  have no idea why

Comment: That's because you didn't come back, so there was no activity for over a week and the room has now been deleted.

Comment: Could you please set up a new room?

Comment: I can do, but not if you intend to disappear for over a week again. You first posted your issue back in late December, which makes me wonder if you are serious about fixing it.

Comment: I won't. I actually pinged you almost a week before you responded. I thought that you hadn't gotten a notice so I deleted my last post twice to repost it. When you did reply I wasn't paying attention as I figured that it might take a while before you responded

Comment: @Christian Wittrock Another room has been created called 'P. Benson - C.Wittrock'. You will have to login/register with Stack Exchange Network before you can use it. So in the next 24 hours try sending me a message from there for testing.

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows boot manager option that disappeared is the NVRAM boot option, you can just add that back by add boot option method in BIOS. It might be present in the boot order configuration page in BIOS. Just try the add option, and locate the Windows boot manager, (probably in YourDrive/Microsoft/[bootmgr.efi or bootmgfw.efi]). Mine is Dell laptop so my add boot manager option is present in the BIOS boot order customization page. You might find it somewhere there.

I think for UEFI, you need to use bootmgfw.efi. :).